# Which photo storage sites allow hotlinking?

Tags: webapp-rec

Which online photo/image sites allow you to hotlink your images from that site?

For those that do, are there any caps on bandwidth usage for hotlinking?

Comment: Voted to close, as after deleting my answer for referencing an old blog post, I realised that hotlinking and bandwidth policies are subject to change and thus too localised.

Comment: @Simon Brown that's why SE-type sites allow you to edit questions and answers. Because the information changes over time. :-)

Comment: I've added a question on meta regarding this.

http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97/are-questions-regarding-site-policies-on-topic

Comment: I agree with @Robert Cartaino on this (http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97/are-questions-regarding-site-policies-on-topic/99#99), it seems harsh to close because local policies are variable.

Answer (score 5):

[Picasa Web Albums](https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?hl=en_US&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fpicasaweb.google.com%2Flh%2Flogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpicasaweb.google.com%252Fhome&service=lh2&ltmpl=gp&passive=true#utm_medium=embed&utm_source=pwalogin) allows hotlinking and up to 1 Gigabyte of storage.

Answer (score 4):

I use [ImageShack](http://imageshack.us/) that allows hotlink.

> If an image is hotlinked, it will have
>   a limit during our peak traffic.
>   Imageshack allows 2000mb per hour for
>   each image hosted. Gif images are
>   limited at 500mb per hour. Peak time
>   is from 6:00am to 3:00pm PST.

You can find additional info on [FAQ](http://imageshack.us/content.php?page=faq) page

Answer (score 4):

For quick one-off and perhaps throw-away images, 
  http://imgur.com has been good to me.

Easy to use, no account nonsense, and hot-linking supported.

The only caveat I find with it is images over 1MB get re-compressed.

Answer (score 2):

[Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/)'s public folder lets you do images (and pretty much any file type). 2 GB of free space, 20 GB of daily traffic for free accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Flickr supports hotlinking as well, and they expose those URLs in the new "share this" menu item, and even have tools for posting embedded photos directly to your blog.

Comment: Note that you must link back to Flickr if you hotlink any of their photos. It is not recommended if you want to use the photos as (for example) graphics on a website.