# Free image hosting service

Tags: webapp-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Photo storage sites allow for hot-linking](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/925/which-photo-storage-sites-allow-for-hot-linking)

I want to start a personal blog and I am looking for a free image hosting service to display images in blog posts. Please also mention the limits of a proposed service.

Answer (score 2):

Flickr http://flickr.com

Limitations: 
- 2 videos and 100 MB worth of photos each month
- 10 MB limit per photo
- Photostream view is limited to 200 photos at any point of time.
- Ads

Comment: But I think its great enough for a personal blog. Just create an account for your blog and you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

### [Picasa](http://picasaweb.google.com/)

This is a photo hosting service from Google. A free account allows you to upload 1 GB of images to an online album, but $5 a year raises the limit to 20 GB of storage. Picasa allows image embedding to post images on blogs.

Answer (score 0):

[Photobucket](http://photobucket.com/) is a good option in addition to Flickr.

Your bandwidth is limited to 10Gb a month which should be more than enough for a blog that is just starting.

If you hit the limits, you can also convert to a Pro account.

Comment: Also related to Photobucket is TinyPic (who Photobucket apparently owns; I still have no idea why they continue to operate both sites. http://tinypic.com/

Answer (score 0):

## [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com/)

> Imgur makes sharing images with the Internet easy. It can be used to share pictures with friends, as well as post images on message boards and blogs. You can manipulate the image a number of ways and automatically submit it to popular sites such as reddit or digg. You can also view popular user-submitted images in the gallery. Best of all, Imgur is completely free.

There's a limit on file sizes if you use the free service:

> The maximum non-animated file size you can upload is 10MB. However, if the image is over 1MB then it will automatically be compressed or resized to 1MB, for better viewing on the net. The maximum animated file size (both GIF and PNG) is 2MB.

Getting a [paid account](https://imgur.com/register/upgrade) removes most limits too for less than 25$/year.

Comment: The link says it, but just to point it out also, only the most recent 225 images are visible with the free account.

Comment: @rchern The images are not deleted so they can still be linked to, they just don't appear in the account so it's a bit harder to manage.